# Group list to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-itertools

Given the list

```
l = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 5), ('b', 3)]
```

how do I get the dictionary

```
{'a': [1, 1, 2], 'c': [5], 'b': [2, 3]}
```

in Python?

Edit: I was looking for a functional solution (using only 1 expression).

Comment: There's an almost exact example for what you want [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples)

Comment: @DavidG You are right, let's mark it as duplicate. Originally, I was looking for a generic one-expression solution to the problem, but I didn't make this clear and the non-functional solution is simpler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use the `collections.defaultdict()`. Alternatively, in case you do not want to import `collections` , you may achieve the same behavior with normal dict using [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) as:

```
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> l = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 5), ('b', 3)]
>>> for k, v in l:
...     my_dict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
...
>>> my_dict
{'a': [1, 1, 2], 'c': [5], 'b': [2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 1):

After defining

```
from itertools import *

def group(iterable, key, value = lambda x: x):
    return dict((k, list(map(value, values))) for k, values in groupby(sorted(iterable, key = key), key))
```

use `group(l, key = lambda x: x[0], value = lambda x: x[1]))`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from the collections module.
You can iterate the list and extract the (key, value) pairs from the tuples in the list and build your dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 5), ('b', 3)]

def dict_my_list(lst):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for key, value in lst:
        d[key].append(value)
    return d

print dict_my_list(l)  # {'a': [1, 1, 2], 'c': [5], 'b': [2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution to your problem using `dict()`

```
l = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 5), ('b', 3)]
ll = dict()
for key,value in l:
    if key in ll:
        ll[key].append(value)
    else:
        ll[key] = list()
        ll[key].append(value)

print ll  # {'a': [1, 1, 2], 'c': [5], 'b': [2, 3]}
```